# Setting range on a rand using cin integers

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to set the parameters or range for my rands on Friday, Saturday and Sunday so they will only display numbers between minimumSnowfall entered and maximumSnowfall entered. How would one go about doing this? I know how to seed a random number, but have no idea on setting a range. Simple terms if you please(I'm still learning).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(void)

{
    int minimumSnowfall;
    int maximumSnowfall;
    char skiResortName[81];


    cout << "I will forecast how much snowfall there will be on each \nday this weekend. You get to pick the range. " << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the minimum amount of snow that \nwill fall in one day in inches: ";
    cin >> minimumSnowfall;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');


    cout << "Please enter the maximum amount of snow that \nwill fall in one day in inches: ";
    cin >> maximumSnowfall;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');



    if (minimumSnowfall < maximumSnowfall)
    {

        cout << "Enter the name of the ski resort: ";
        cin.getline(skiResortName, 81);
        cout << "\nThe local forecast for snowfall at " << skiResortName << " this weekend: " << endl;
        cout << "Friday: " << rand() % 100 << " inches" << endl;
        cout << "Saturday: " << rand() % 100 << " inches" << endl;
        cout << "Sunday: " << rand() % 100 << " inches" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nThe maximum snowfall entered is less than the minimum snowfall. " << endl;
        cout << "No snowfall reported.\n" << endl;
    }









    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're just printing the address of the `rand` function. You need to put parentheses after the name to call it: `rand()`

Comment: You are correct, I did that. Now my numbers are down between 0-99.. but how can I specify the range to be between what the user entered for minimum snowfall and the user entered for maximum snowfall?

Comment: The usual way would be something like `rand() % maximum`

Comment: And that guarantees to be between the integers entered by user: minimumSnowfall and maximumSnowfall?

Comment: No, that guarantees integers less than maximum. To get in a range, you'd use `rand() % (maximum - minimum) + minimum`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I flagged your comment up.